# How to Convert a Nullable DateTime variable's null value to DbNull.Value

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, nullable, dbcommand

I have a nullable DateTime Variable. And I want to write it to SQL DB. When i try to insert:

If the variable has value there is no problem.

But if it hasn't a value, insertion interrupting with an error.

I want to ask: How can we insert nullable DateTime to Sql via DbCommand Parameter?

(P.S. : Sql column is nullable too.)

```
DateTime? myDate = null;
DbCommand dbCommand = new DbCommand();
dbCommand.Parameters.Add("NullableSqlDateField", DbType.DateTime, myDate);
```

Comment: What's the error you get? I believe you *can* use `null` and `DBNull.Value` interchangeably.

Comment: @Yuck - I don't think you can use the two interchangeably, or at the very least, you can't with all database providers.  You should use DBNull.Value when inserting null values into a database.  There is a slight difference in semantics when dealing with null vs. DBNull.Value: null refers to an invalid object reference, whereas DBNull.Value refers to an unknown value in a database row.  Seems like hair-splitting, but it's the best reasoning I can see for the difference.

Comment: @mjd79 It works with `SqlDbCommand`, maybe just not with `DbCommand`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try the [null coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx):

```
dbCommand.Parameters.Add("NullableSqlDateField", DbType.DateTime, (object) myDate ?? DbNull.Value);
```

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that this is not handled by the db provider.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if(myDate.HasValue)
  dbCommand.Parameters.Add("NullableSqlDateField", DbType.DateTime, myDate.Value);
else
  dbCommand.Parameters.Add("NullableSqlDateField", DbType.DateTime, DbNull.Value);
```