# Compiler Error CS0173 TypeConvertion

Tags: c#

I get the Error

> Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'System.DateTime' and'System.DBNull'

with the Code (in the 3rd line)

```
DateTime? BirthDate = GetDate(PersonID);
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand myCommand = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(cStatement, myConnection);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BirthDate", BirthDate.HasValue ? BirthDate.Value : DBNull.Value);
```

How can i avoid this error?

Comment: Also, this question answers this already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669107/how-to-convert-a-nullable-datetime-variables-null-value-to-dbnull-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast to an object.

```
DateTime? BirthDate = GetDate(PersonID);
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand myCommand = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(cStatement, myConnection);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BirthDate", BirthDate.HasValue ? (object)BirthDate.Value : DBNull.Value);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can cast it to object:

```
 myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BirthDate", BirthDate.HasValue ? (object) BirthDate.Value : (object) DBNull.Value);
```

The reason behind the error is that each result of your expression

```
condition ? result1 : result2;
```

Has a different type, so the compiler cannot work out the return type of it. By casting to `object` you are allowing the compiler to infer that the return type is `object` as both results of the expresion belongs to that type (every class inherits from object)